# Question in using "and also"

Tags: grammar

I am drafting a sentence like this:

```
I aim at doing XXX, and also doing YYY
```

As far as I can see, after "and also" I should use `doing` as to be consistent with the first `doing`. However, someone told me that it is more common to use `do` following the `and also`.

Could anyone shed some lights here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all you should say "I aim to do XXX" therefore in the second sentence you should say "and also to YYY" since you no longer need "do" or "doing" in the second sentence.
I aim at doing something. = I strive to do something.
I aim to do something. = I attempt/plan to do something.
If you're actually going for the meaning of "aim at", you probably wouldn't put "doing" before your XXX and YYY. It'd go like this:
"I aim at getting my startup started,and finishing university at the same time/simultaneously."
"I aim at cleaning the house before the guests arrive, and buying groceries as well."

 So you're going for a verb with ing for the second one.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Then if the first and the second verbs are not the same, let's say `I aim to work on XXX, and also design YYY`. Should I say `and also to design` or `and also design`?

Comment: Yes that's work,no "to" needed although it's exactly wrong to put it there, you could get rid of the"also" as well but it might not get your point entirely across. read my answer again i added some stuff

Comment: @Virgilius I think there is a typo in your answer. You may grammatically say "I aim to build a house and also to build a barn" or "I aim to build a house and also a barn." But it is not grammatical to say "I aim to build a house and also to barn" as you imply in your first paragraph. By the way, nice work on the distinction between "aim to" and "aiming at."

Comment: @jeff-morrow I see why you'd think that's what i'm implying, but since there are many different formulas you can put as XXX or YYY i can't account for all of them, I assumed that the YYY is a verb not a noun.

Comment: You go on to explain what 'I aim at doing something' means, so your 'Well, first of all you should say "I aim to do XXX" ' is illogical.

Comment: @edwin-ashworth I have absolutely no idea what you're talking about, OP was talking about "aim at", i corrected him and explained the difference, what's your problem?

Comment: _You_ came up with 'Well, first of all you should say "I aim to do XXX" '. But what OP has is quite acceptable. 'I aim at doing well in German, and also doing even better in Science.' The problem is of your own invention.